# Implement a Social Login without Sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, oauth, shopify

I have implemented a Twitch login on my Shopify website, but how do I persist the authenticated user across my website's pages? Normally this would be done with a session ID, but this being Shopify I cannot access session variables. Is it OK to substitute a regular cookie for this?

1. User clicks Twitch Login button on my site
2. Oauth authentication takes place, I get access token, etc.
3. User is redirected back to my site...now what? When they click to go to a different page, how do I know it's the same user who logged in on the previous page? I'm guessing when they're first redirect back to my site, I create a unique ID and store in a database, then send the ID back (possibly in the URL, or header?) and the client stores that ID in a cookie (via Javascript). Now every page refresh I get that ID from the cookie, send it to my server which checks it against the ID in the database...if it matches, I display the user the page.

Comment: You need to provide more details. But yes. Do indeed use cookies! That is what they are made for!

Comment: I provided some elaboration in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [Multipass](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/multipass) from Shopify REST Admin API

There is also Node.js module available for this integration on GitHub [beaucoo/multipassify](https://github.com/beaucoo/multipassify)

The authentication flow will look something like this:

1. Authenticate from a 3rd party like Twitch (You've done this)
2. Encode your customer data the way specified in Shopify Multipass API
3. Redirect the customer to `https://yourstorename.myshopify.com/account/login/multipass/<MULTIPASS-TOKEN>`

Comment: Ok got it, Multipass is Shopify Plus only unfortunately. My understanding is this would be the best and most secure way. But also that the method I described in my question would work, but would just be less secure?

Comment: Your way would only work for *displaying the user name / email*, think about how would you display user's **order history** and **delivery address**, these are out of the box features from Shopify.